# What is the Pythonic way to query a dataframe row for a keyword and manipulate the same row based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, series

Lets say I have a the following pandas data frame with the following columnar structure and the dataframe is titled `df`

```
index column1 column2 column3
0     2       5       apple
1     4       3       apple
2     6       1       orange 
3     8       6       apple 
4    10       5       orange
```

I would like to search the dataframe such that it will recognize every row where `df['column3'] == orange` and extract the value of `df['column2']` in that row and insert it into the below function and then change the existing value of `df[column2']` by the output of the function.

```
def func(x):
    return x * 2.0
```

Thus far I have implemented the following, which works, but I suspect it is not the most pythonic way of doing this, and probably does not have the most efficient execution speed.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.loc[i, 'column3'] == 'orange':
        df.loc[i, 'column2'] = func(df.column2)
```

Comment: Without knowing what `func` actually is, it is impossible to answer. You can reduce the usage loc accesses with apply but that's not an efficient way either.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use an explicit loop. Here's one solution via [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    return x * 2.0

mask = df['column3'] == 'orange'

df.loc[mask, 'column2'] = df.loc[mask, 'column2'].apply(func)

print(df)

   index  column1  column2 column3
0      0        2      5.0   apple
1      1        4      3.0   apple
2      2        6      2.0  orange
3      3        8      6.0   apple
4      4       10     10.0  orange
```

However, if you operation can be vectorised, as in this case, you should use vectorised operations. For example:

```
df.loc[df['column3'] == 'orange', 'column2'] *= 2
```

Since NumPy arrays, which are behind numeric series in Pandas, work better with vectorised solutions than with explicit loops, you will see performance benefits cross over to Pandas.

Comment: Ley me take this one step further.  Let's say that function `func` takes two input variables, which are `'df[column1]'` and `'df[column2]'`; howe would I implement that.  I just tried adding `df.loc[mask, 'column2'] = df.loc[mask, 'column1', 'column2'].apply(func)` and it yielded an exception.

Comment: @Jon, That's a completely different question. In that case you'd use `pd.DataFrame.apply`. Which has a different syntax and a different purpose. I've rolled back your question because you shouldn't *change* your question once it's been answered. Feel free to ask a new question if you're stuck on `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

Comment: I respect your decision, but I disagree.  The crux of the question is how to pass information from a dataframe to a function and return the result to the dataframe.  The number of arguments does indeed change the answer, but not the question.

Comment: @Jon, It's tempting to *believe* there's a single solution / method for both scenarios. Unfortunately, there isn't. But more importantly, your post did not ask the more general question.

Comment: The question has been re-posted